# Is there a way to use Node to update the value for a specific JSON key in an external JSON file WITHOUT having to parse and stringify the entire file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am aware of `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`. I understand that I can use Node's `fs` to then write out the 'new' JSON data back to the file.

However, if I only need to replace 1 value for a specific key, it doesn't feel like I should need to `parse()` the entire JSON file each time.

So, to summarize, my JS will create a new value. That value should then be written back to the JSON file, but, I want to be able to update the value for just the 1 specific key inside of having to `parse` and then `stringify` the whole JSON file each and every time just for the 1 value.

Comment: Unless the file is *insanely huge*, parsing and re-stringifying it will be **simpler and safer** than anything else. If you do have insanely huge files and it becomes a performance issue, you need to think about storing your data in different files first and foremost, and secondarily perhaps look at stream parsers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need node then, using `sed` with a regex for replacement is clearly enough.
Though you can still use NodeJS and regex using `String.prototype.replace`.

Using `sed`

```
sed -i 's/\"key\":.*/\"key\": '${newValue}'/g' "/path/to/my.json"
```

Using NodeJS

```
let file = fs.readFileSync('./a.json').toString();
file = file.replace(/\"key\":.*/g, '"key": "newValue"');
fs.writeFileSync('./a.json', file);
```

If the file doesn't have a **significant** size, it's not necessary to opt for this type of solution, just `parse` and `stringify` back to the file

Comment: Yikes. That does seem more complicated than just 'parsing and stringifying' as per comment above.

Comment: @CodeFinity Yes I agree, but that's what the author asked for haha !